# How to remove keys from a params array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a list of params.

I have a `sales_attributes` key, which can contain an unlimited array of hashes.

I'm trying to remove the `name` and `code` keys and values from each `sales_attributes` array.

I tried iterating over each sales_attributes and doing `delete`, `except` or `reject`, but they only return the sales_attributes instead of the original param list. I want to return the exact same list as below, but not including the `name` or `code` key/values.

I looked at quite a few other posts on here and nothing has worked so far.

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"patient_id"=>"22", "location_id"=>"5", "practitioner_id"=>"1", "confidential"=>"1", "billpayer_id"=>"20", "sales_attributes"=>
[<ActionController::Parameters {"sellable_type"=>"Product",
"sellable_id"=>"-2", "discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0", "name"=>"first",
"code"=>"G32"} permitted: true>, <ActionController::Parameters
{"sellable_type"=>"Product", "sellable_id"=>"-2", "discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0", "name"=>"second", "code"=>"G33"} permitted: true>,
<ActionController::Parameters {"sellable_type"=>"Product",
"sellable_id"=>"-2", "discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0", "name"=>"third", "code"=>"G34"} permitted: true>]} permitted: true>
```

Comment: There is no code, there's a variable dump. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 3):

In Rails, the general philosophy with parameters is that you should whitelist attributes to maintain more control over what you are exposing, instead of blacklisting and possibly accidentally exposing something private in the future.

Along those lines, you can cherry-pick all the attributes in the `:sale_attributes` array, except those you don't want and `permit` access to those alone:

```
# abbreviated parameters, from @Cary Swoveland
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  "patient_id"=>"22", "sales_attributes"=>[
    { "type"=>"Product1", "price"=>"0", "name"=>"first", "code"=>"G32" },
    { "type"=>"Product2", "price"=>"1", "name"=>"second", "code"=>"G33" }, 
    { "type"=>"Product3", "price"=>"3", "name"=>"third", "code"=>"G34" }
  ]
})

params.permit(:patient_id, sales_attributes: [:type, :price])
# => <ActionController::Parameters {"patient_id"=>"22", 
    "sales_attributes"=>[
      <ActionController::Parameters {"type"=>"Product1", "price"=>"0"} permitted: true>,
      <ActionController::Parameters {"type"=>"Product2", "price"=>"1"} permitted: true>,
      <ActionController::Parameters {"type"=>"Product3", "price"=>"3"} permitted: true>]} permitted: true>
```

Comment: Nice one! I just focused on transforming the parameters, but this is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a "copy" of params where you modify the `sales_attribute` values:

```
params.each_with_object({}) do |(key, values), hash|
  hash[key] = if key == :sales_attributes
                values.map do |sales_attribute|
                  sales_attribute.except(:code, :name)
                end
              else
                hash[key] = values
              end
end
# { "patient_id"=>"22", "location_id"=>"5", "practitioner_id"=>"1", "confidential"=>"1", "billpayer_id"=>"20", "sales_attributes"=>
#  [{"sellable_type"=>"Product", "sellable_id"=>"-2", "discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0"},
#   {"sellable_type"=>"Product", "sellable_id"=>"-2", "discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0"},
#   {"sellable_type"=>"Product", "sellable_id"=>"-2", "discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0"}] }
```

Basically, you iterate params and assign every key/value to a temporal hash, but in case the key is equal to `:sales_attributes` then you map the values using `except` and get their keys/values except `:code` and `:name`.

Answer (score 1):

We are given (simplified from the example in the question):

```
params = {
  "patient_id"=>"22", "sales_attributes"=>[
    { "type"=>"Product1", "price"=>"0", "name"=>"first", "code"=>"G32" },
    { "type"=>"Product2", "price"=>"1", "name"=>"second", "code"=>"G33" }, 
    { "type"=>"Product3", "price"=>"3", "name"=>"third", "code"=>"G34" }
  ]
}
```

and

```
unwanted_keys = ["name", "code"]
```

We can then obtain the desired hash as follows.

```
params.merge("sales_attributes"=>unwanted_keys) do |_key,old_val,new_val|
  old_val.map { |h| h.reject { |k,_| new_val.include?(k) } }
end
  #=> {"patient_id"=>"22", "sales_attributes"=>[
  #     {"type"=>"Product1", "price"=>"0"},
  #     {"type"=>"Product2", "price"=>"1"},
  #     {"type"=>"Product3", "price"=>"3"}
  #    ]
  #   }
```

The uses the form of [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. The only key common to both `params` and `{ "sales_attributes"=>unwanted_keys }` is `"sales_attributes"`, so that it is the only key for which the block is called.

When the block is called,

```
_key = "sales_attributes"
old_val = [
  { "type"=>"Product1", "price"=>"0", "name"=>"first", "code"=>"G32" },
  { "type"=>"Product2", "price"=>"1", "name"=>"second", "code"=>"G33" }, 
  { "type"=>"Product3", "price"=>"3", "name"=>"third", "code"=>"G34" }
]
new_val = unwanted_keys
  #=> ["name", "code"]
```

so

```
old_val.map { |h| h.reject { |k,_| new_val.include?(k) } }
  #=> [{"type"=>"Product1", "price"=>"0"},
  #    {"type"=>"Product2", "price"=>"1"},
  #    {"type"=>"Product3", "price"=>"3"}]
```

becomes the value of `"sales_attributes"` in the merged hash.

I used `_key`, rather than `key`, for the first block variable to signal to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation. I might instead have written just `_`, which is often used for block variables not used in the block calculation. Unlike other local variables, `_` can represent multiple block variables (e.g, `|_,a,_,b|`).

Use [Hash#merge!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) (a.k.a `update`) if `params` is to be mutated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `each_with_object`, which is handy for building hashes or reducing collections down to one object:

```
params = {"patient_id"=>"22", "location_id"=>"5", "practitioner_id"=>"1", "confidential"=>"1", "billpayer_id"=>"20",  
"sales_attributes"=> [{ "sellable_type"=>"Product", "sellable_id"=>"-2", "discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0", "name"=>"first", "code"=>"G32" }, 
{ "sellable_type"=>"Product", "sellable_id"=>"-2", "discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0", "name"=>"second", "code"=>"G33" }, 
{ "sellable_type"=>"Product", "sellable_id"=>"-2", "discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0", "name"=>"third", "code"=>"G34" }
  ]}
```

Solution:

```
result = {}
params.each_with_object(result) do |(key, values)|
  if key == 'sales_attributes'
    result[key] =  values.map { |sales_attribute| sales_attribute.except('name', 'code') }
  else
    result[key] = values
  end
end
```

Resulting hash output:

```
=> {"patient_id"=>"22", "location_id"=>"5", "practitioner_id"=>"1", "confidential"=>"1", 
"billpayer_id"=>"20", "sales_attributes"=>[{"sellable_type"=>"Product", "sellable_id"=>"-2", 
"discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0"}, {"sellable_type"=>"Product", "sellable_id"=>"-2", 
"discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0"}, {"sellable_type"=>"Product", "sellable_id"=>"-2", 
"discount"=>"0", "price"=>"0"}]}
```

Comment: `reject { ....include?(...) }` is the Ruby way for Rails `except`. If using Rails why wouldn't you just use `except`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It is better to use only except instead of both reject and include.